# IntelliJ and Java - Cucumber unable to find step definitions

Tags: java, selenium, intellij-idea, cucumber

I know there are several similar questions, but as far as I can see no one has a general solution, or in any case no solutions that are relevant or works for me.

I've got an existing project with Cucumber and Selenium tests in Java.

From the test definition files (.feature), IntelliJ is able to find the test steps in the Java classes. And I can follow the links back and forth between the features and the steps.

However, when I try to run a test (either a whole feature file or a specific test in the file), I get:

```
Undefined scenarios:/home/frank/Desktop/repos_00/saksbehandling/e2e/cucumber/src/test/resources/features/bolig/konkret_bolig.feature:17 # Søker har søkt om konkret boli
```

It's not a glue thing; I know about that problem, but the glue in the configirations is automatically created correctly:

[image]

I don't see how it can be a Plugin thing either, since if Cucumber for Java wasn't installed or not working, I don't think IntelliJ would be able to see the connection between the steps and the step definitions.

Comment: Try removing the glue. Recent versions scan from the classpath root when none is provided.

Comment: Didn't help. I'd like a way to FORCE the irritatingly unstable cucumber plugin, but it doesn't seem to be possible.

Comment: I have to say - this is just insanely unstable and completely useless. It suddenly started working. All I did was remove the glue and paste it back again, and it started working. Then, after half a day or so, it suddenly stopped working again. This is useless c**p, plain and simple.

Comment: I'm getting this exact problem too - my current workaround is to run the tests using a file annotated with @RunWith(Cucumber.class) and the correct glue location. But I'd like to just be able to run the feature file directly. I can't see anything obviously wrong with the launch config or anything.

Edit: aand - I tried removing the glue, and then the broken run configuration, and suddenly it started working. Hm.